# Phase shift in a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

This is how i am writing code

```
fc = 10;
td = 5000;
fs = 3*fc;
ts = 1/fs;
t = 0:ts:1-ts;
a = cos(2*pi*fc*t);
figure, plot(a);
Y = fftshift(fft(a));
nfft = length(Y);
p = 0:fs/nfft:1-fs/nfft;
p1 = Y.*exp(-1i*2*pi*p*td);
p2 = ifft(ifftshift(p1));
figure, plot(abs(p2));
```

This is the result which i achieve. However the signal with phase shift is same like the signal without phaseshift.

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay a signal in time domain with a phase change in the frequency domain after FFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586803/delay-a-signal-in-time-domain-with-a-phase-change-in-the-frequency-domain-after)

Comment: Don't mix two solutions, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a delay in the FT domain by multiplying by `exp(-1i*2*pi*p*td)`, it's right.

But `fft` is not centered by default (use `fftshift` for that), the DC is at index 1. So `p` is not right, try `p = 0:fs/nfft:1-fs/nfft;` instead.

**EDIT:** Seems not completely clear. If you use `p = 0:fs/nfft:1-fs/nfft;`, don't use `fftshift`. If you want to use `fftshift`, p must be `-1/2+fs/nfft:fs/nfft:1/2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a phase shift you only have to do:

```
a = cos(2*pi*fc*t + S);
```

where S is the shift (in radians). 

 Also, if you still want to plot the `ifft(p1)` you shouldn't do `abs(p2)` but `real(p2)`.

 I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, underscore_nico. However, above mentioned method i can also use right? Using fft and ifft?